# f.error_messages only shows first error message in base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, error-handling

I've simplified my problem to the following: `f.error_messages` only displays the first error on base. To replicate, do the following:

```
errors.add_to_base "Error 1"
errors.add_to_base "Error 2"
```

Then print the messages on the view (i.e. `<%= f.error_messages %>`), and observe that only "Error 1" appears, but not "Error 2"! Further, examine `errors.full_messages` and observe that it indeed holds both errors. Its value is `["Error 1", "Error 2"]`.

Can anyone replicate this issue? More importantly... can anyone tell me how to get `f.error_messages` to print ALL errors?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Actually, I have class A has_one class B. And I'm adding to base on class B, and calling `f.error_messages` on class A. It looks like if I do the following, it shows the full list of errors from class B:

```
<% class_a.fields_for :class_b do |class_b| %>
  <%= class_b.object.errors.full_messages.join("<br />") %>
<% end %>
```

However if I call `errors` on the parent, it does **not** work.

```
<%= class_a.object.errors.full_messages.join("<br />") %>
```

That only displays the first error from class B (i.e. "Error 1"). Obviously, class A accepts_nested_attributes_for :class_b.

Lastly, I am on Rails 2.3.11.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle it as an array, not as a single value you can print.

```
<% f.error_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <%= msg %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: this doesn't work. but actually i just discovered another piece of the puzzle, and i've updated the question accordingly. it seems to be caused by the fact that i'm using a nested form, and the errors are added to the child object.